# how can I download Google Cloud Storage object by metadata info

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Document here :
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#getobject

I  use this  function  try to Download  a  obejct.  But  only can response   metadata info

> getFile: (file_id, callback)->
>
> ```
> log("getFileMetadata") 
> unless callback 
>   callback = (resp) ->
>     log  "Read Complete" ,resp
>
> params =  
>   path : "/storage/v1beta2/b/#{@BUCKET}/o/#{file_id}"
>   method : "GET"
>   headers:
>     host: "storage.googleapis.com" 
>     "If-Modified-Since" : "Fri, 19 Feb 2001 22:04:23 GMT"
> alert("12 storage.googleapis.com")
> ```
>
> gapi.client.request(paramas,callback)

Answer (score 2):

The `selfLink` field points to the canonical URL containing the metadata for the object. To get the object's contents, you should use the `mediaLink` field.

Comment: hey, I  find  google cloud storage object.get api  can download  the  data. But  I  only  can response metadata. cannot  get data even I  specificate "If-Modified-Since" header

Comment: are you using the `alt=media` query parameter?

Comment: No, seems  not  required

Comment: Right, it's not required, but it defaults to `alt=json`, which returns metadata. If you want media, you need to specify `alt=media`.

Comment: I  have  added  alt= media ,   it  responsed  "A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed."

Comment: my bucket  and  file  have  Reader rol for  all.  And  it request url like this:https://content.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/waiter-code-sample-bucket/o/desktop.ini?alt=media&generation=1382518523209000&key=AIzaSyBVDs0bXkbSuflogzPL_JgMUPgRPXSDcCc

Comment: Try: `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/bucketname/o/objectname?alt=media`

Comment: still doesnt't work....  Do you know  why   responsed "A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed." ??

Comment: You will have to enable CORS if you're trying to download from JS. You might also want to look at the [Metabucket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-metabucket-javascript) JS example.

Comment: Hey Metabucket JS example.  can download public object. But  How can I get  private object  by request???

Answer (score 1):

Also had problems trying to download a file using the Google_Storage_Service.

Once I list my object in a given bucket I get an array of items, which each have a media link containing a URL to my file which looks something like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/<bucket>/o/<object>?generation=1234567890&alt=media
```

So naturally I try and download this file using Google_Http_Request (perhaps there is a better way?)

```
$request = new \Google_Http_Request($item->getMediaLink(), 'GET');
$httpRequest = $this->googleClient->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
```

But I got an error message saying....

```
*The document has moved <A HREF="https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>?generation=1234567890">here</A>*
```

So downloading from the following works, note the change in the sub domain

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>?generation=1234567890
```